# Interaction between Chrome extension popups and DOM w/o running into CSS conflicts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

After many hours of research, I've seen multiple ways to do similar things. But I don't want to pigeonhole myself into approaching this in the wrong way, so I would appreciate any advice on how to achieve the following.

When clicking on my extension icon, I want to load a toolbar onto the current page. This toolbar has a number of links and forms that can:

1. Interact with the original page (DOM Listeners, changing the DOM)
2. Create additional extension popups on the original page
3. Make requests to external resources

From a JS perspective, I think it would be easiest to inject all my own HTML directly on the page and handle functionality via one content script. I abandoned that approach after realizing I'd never be able to account for all CSS conflicts in my popups.

So instead, this is what I have so far. When clicking on my Extension icon, I inject a div into the current page and load up an iframe sourced to a `popup.html` via `chrome.extension.getURL('popup1.html')`. This is where I get stuck. By loading my content into an iframe, I have isolated any CSS issues. But say I have text selected on the parent page and I click a button in my `popup1.html`. Is there then a way to pass the selected text back to the `popup1.html` or to show that selected text in a new `popup2.html`?

I hope that once I get the workflow down on how to do this kind of interaction I can move on with development. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was considering taking an approach similar to [this one by Matthew McEachen](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/sandbox-telegrams-or-how-your-chrome-extension-can-interact-with-page-content-scripts-1123.html), but I wasn't sure if that's still the best way to do it considering that article is 2+ years old.

Comment: I ended up finding a recently-published article on this very subject. It has been enormously helpful in helping me understand how the different environments in Chrome extensions can talk to each other:

http://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-extensions-bridging-the-gap-between-layers/